# Efficiently duplicate dataframe rows according to a different table

Tags: python, pandas, merge, left-join

I need to add modified copies of its own rows to a dataframe according to a separate table, but it needs to run over millions of rows and I am having problems optimizing it.

I have a dataframe df where one identifier is a certain column 'myIndex'

```
    df=pd.DataFrame([
                 {'myIndex':1,'dummyData':2,'type':'test'},
                 {'myIndex':1,'dummyData':3,'type':'test'},
                 {'myIndex':1,'dummyData':4,'type':'other'},
                 {'myIndex':2,'dummyData':22,'type':'test'},
                 {'myIndex':2,'dummyData':32,'type':'test'},
                 {'myIndex':2,'dummyData':42,'type':'other'},
                 {'myIndex':3,'dummyData':23,'type':'test'},
                 {'myIndex':3,'dummyData':33,'type':'test'},
                 {'myIndex':3,'dummyData':43,'type':'other'}
                 ])
```

I have to duplicate its rows according to a table in another dataframe

```
    repeatedRows=pd.DataFrame([
                           {'myIndex':1,'idx2':21},
                           {'myIndex':1,'idx2':31},
                           {'myIndex':1,'idx2':42},
                           {'myIndex':2,'idx2':221},
                           {'myIndex':2,'idx2':231},
                           {'myIndex':2,'idx2':242},
                           {'myIndex':3,'idx2':321},
                           {'myIndex':3,'idx2':331},
                           {'myIndex':4,'idx2':342}
                           ])
```

So a df row whose myIndex appears in repeatedRows should be replicated with 'myIndex' replaced by idx2, and  'type' replaced by 'duplicate'. This is my latest attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None # Avoid annoying warning
def Test1(df,repeatedRows):
    for idx in set(repeatedRows['myIndex']):
        vals=df[df['myIndex']==idx]
        for n in repeatedRows[repeatedRows['myIndex']==idx].loc[:,'idx2']:
            vals.loc[:,'myIndex']=n
            vals.loc[:,'type']='duplicate'
            df=pd.concat([df,vals],ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

This is the expected outcome:

```
untitled0.Test1()
Out[44]: 
    dummyData  myIndex       type
0           2        1       test
1           3        1       test
2           4        1      other
3          22        2       test
4          32        2       test
5          42        2      other
6          23        3       test
7          33        3       test
8          43        3      other
9           2       21  duplicate
10          3       21  duplicate
11          4       21  duplicate
12          2       31  duplicate
13          3       31  duplicate
14          4       31  duplicate
15          2       42  duplicate
16          3       42  duplicate
17          4       42  duplicate
18         22      221  duplicate
19         32      221  duplicate
20         42      221  duplicate
21         22      231  duplicate
22         32      231  duplicate
23         42      231  duplicate
24         22      242  duplicate
25         32      242  duplicate
26         42      242  duplicate
27         23      321  duplicate
28         33      321  duplicate
29         43      321  duplicate
30         23      331  duplicate
31         33      331  duplicate
32         43      331  duplicate
```

I have implemented it in a few different ways but it still takes a long time, I guess I am doing something very inefficient, or not taking full advantage of pandas. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is manually trying to do a merge/join. Please read [the doc on pandas merge/join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link @smci , I will give it a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to merge both dataframes, do your modification and concat it back to `df`:

```
mer = df.merge(repeatedRows, how='left')
mer['myIndex'] = mer['idx2']
mer['type'] = 'duplicate'
df = pd.concat([df, mer.drop(['idx2'], axis=1)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that was fast! Your solution is very elegant and the time dropped to less than one third. Still getting my head around it, but... nicely done!

Comment: Glad to help. @AlePorro.